# Java Socket Remote Client-Server

Tags: java, sockets, server, serversocket

I'm trying to make a connection unicast between a client and a server in Java. At the moment, I succeded in writing the code for making a connection between client and server only if the server is the localhost.

Could you tell me how can I make the same connection, but assuming the server is on another computer? Thanks

This below is the file MyServer.java

```java
package clientserver;
import java.net.*;  
import java.io.*;

public class MyServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ServerSocket server=new ServerSocket(3333);
        Socket client=server.accept();
        
        DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        
        String strClient="",strServer="";
        
        while(!strClient.equals("stop")){  
            strClient = din.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Client: "+strClient);

            System.out.print("Enter a message to send to the client: ");
            strServer=br.readLine();
            dout.writeUTF(strServer);
        }
        dout.close();
        client.close();
        server.close();
    }
    
}
```

This below is the file MyClient.java

```java
package clientserver;
import java.net.*;  
import java.io.*;

public class MyClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 3333);
        
        DataInputStream din= new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dout= new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        
        String strClient = "", strServer ="";
        
        while(!strClient.equals("stop")){
            System.out.print("Enter a message to send to the server: ");
            strClient = br.readLine();
            dout.writeUTF(strClient);
            
            strServer = din.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Server: "+strServer);
        }
        
        dout.close();
        s.close();
    }
    
}
```

I think this line of code `Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 3333);` should change, but I don't know into what.

I hope I wrote everything clear. Thanks for your help :D!

Comment: put the IP address of the other computer instead of localhost?

Comment: Yeah, but I wanted to do it in an automatic way (if exists),without changing the IP address everytime I run the program on another computer

Comment: then how should your program know which other computer it is? There could be 2 computers, or 100, or 1000000. Imagine opening a web browser and not telling it which website to go to.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right, I didn't think about it, I'm sorry

Comment: there are some programs that try to connect to "the whole internet" - like bitcoin - but it's not easy and they have to use many tricks to make it work. Making it automatically connect on *just your network* is possible, although I don't know how (I'd have to find out) and you'd still have to figure out what to do if there was more than one server

Comment: Any arbitrary "other computer" is tricky as you would need to ensure that the address were routable and also that port forwarding were set up. If you want it to run on your own LAN, it should do so if you use the LAN IP address of the server. What are your intentions?